# How to set global variable in thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I am using `thymeleaf` in front end and I know `variable` concept in `thymeleaf`

```
<span th:with="var=${someValue}" th:text="${var}"></span>
```

if I use `th:text` the value in the variable will be printed and I can use that variable in the same element, Is there any way to use the `var` in other element like

```
<span th:with="var=${someValue}"></span>

<span th:text="${var}"></span>
```

I need to provide `global scope` to that variable is it possible in thymeleaf ?

Answer (score 7):

Define `var` in the opening `body` tag

```
<body th:with="var=${var_value}">
```

Comment: can't I retrieve variable from one span or div to other?

Comment: afaik, only nested elements can access the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Only nested item can see variable. Div tag is only an example. You can use tags you wants

```
<div th:with="var=${var_value}">

  inside div tag var is visible.

</div>
```

Comment: is it possible that we can change the var value while we iterate a loop inside the div?

Answer (score 1):

Golobal variable is not supported in thymeleaf but it can be achieved through inline javascript.

- Thymeleaf var_value stored in javascript variable 'value' and set the value in input field using JQuery.

```js
<script th:inline="javascript">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
            $(document).ready(function (){
            var Value = /*[[${var_value}]]*/ '';
            $("#ID").val(Value);
            });
        /*]]>*/
    </script>
```

```html
 <input type="text" class="order-entry" id="ID" placeholder="" th:value="${''}" />
```